# Flutter: Horizontal auto Scrolling

Tags: flutter

[image: as shown]

I would like some help with getting the artist names to automatically scroll from right to left (or left to right if that's easier for you) in flutter, but I am not sure how to go about that and would appreciate someone's help :) I have looked into Horizontal ListViews and all but I was getting errors so I didn't move forward with that.

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/danceClub.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
              child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
                  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2))))
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(child: Container(child: Text('Now Playing', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.black),),)),

              _imageURLValue != null ? Image.network(_imageURLValue, height: 300) : Container(),

              Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0)), Text('${_songName}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.amber)), Text(' - ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.black)),
                Expanded(child: ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true, itemCount: _artistsNames == null ? 0 : _artistsNames.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) { return Text(_artistsNames[i], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.blue),);}))]),

              Container(child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                child: Text('Exit to menu'),
              )),

              Container(child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: getData,
                child: Text('Get data from http!', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 20.0)),
              ))
            ],
          )
        ]
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Flutter plugin that seems to match exactly your need:

#### marquee:

https://pub.dev/packages/marquee

> A Flutter widget that scrolls text infinitely. Provides many customizations including custom scroll directions, durations, curves as well as pauses after every round.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to use [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) library

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it's possible to find something in this "carousel_slider" library that make the author words automatically slide from right to left and not overlap with any other objects on the screen? It's kinda hard to explain. Lemme know if my question isn't making sense.

Comment: I don't know actually, but I don't see any potential problem with it.